# findOneAndUpdate is not a function nestjs

Tags: mongoose, graphql, nestjs

Im trying to update a user document when a todo is created. I tried using findOneAndUpdate but it's throwing me an error of findOneAndUpdate is not a function.

This is my snippet of my service.

```
import { Inject, Injectable, forwardRef } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Todo } from './todo.schema';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { todoCreateInput } from './todo.type';

import { User } from '../users/User.schema';

@Injectable()
export class TodoService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(Todo.name)
    private todoModel: Model<Todo>,
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => User))
    @InjectModel(User.name)
    private userModel: Model<User>,
  ) {}

  async create(input: todoCreateInput) {
    const createdTodo = await new this.todoModel(input);
    const user = await this.userModel.findOneAndUpdate(
      { id: input.userId },
      { $push: { todos: createdTodo } },
      { new: true },
    );
    if (!user) {
      throw new Error('User not found');
    }
    return createdTodo.save();
  }
}
```

and this is my User schema

```
@Schema()
@ObjectType()
export class User {
  @Field(() => ID)
  @Prop({ unique: true, required: true, default: v4 })
  id: string;

  @Field()
  @Prop({ unique: true, required: true })
  username: string;

  @Field()
  @Prop({ required: true })
  password: string;

  @Field({ nullable: true })
  @Prop()
  displayName?: string;

  @Field((type) => [Todo], { nullable: 'itemsAndList' })
  @Prop()
  todos: Todo[];
}

export const UserSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(User);
```

I tried just trying to update it like this

```
async create(input: todoCreateInput) {
    const user = await this.userModel.findOneAndUpdate(
      { id: input.userId },
      { $push: { todos: todoCreateInput } },
      { new: true },
    );
    if (!user) {
      throw new Error('User not found');
    }
    return user.save();
  }
```

but it still not wroking.

what am i doing wrong?? thankyou for the time

Comment: - You are using multiple Inject decorators for the User Model!! Remove the @Inject(forwardRef())

- You should create your GraphQL Object and Entity Schema separately because it might confuse the nest metadata processing.